# Can you automate visiting the site consecutive for X days?

Tags: discussion, consecutive-days

Does it count towards the consecutive visited days, if you setup a cron job that opens (e.g. CURL) your stackoverflow profile with a formed HTTP request and a valid login cookie?

Comment: You'd have to be pretty fanatical to do this...

Comment: Those badges really matter to some people!

Comment: Try it out. Show us you have the guts to do it.

Comment: Just why should/would you do that?

Comment: If you were bored or fancied learning something new about HTTP requests, stackoverflow login/cookies, a new networking framework, networking in a new programming language, cron or just really wanted stackoverflow badges?

Comment: Probably yes. (to the question in the title) but I think you would need something more elaborate than just making a single request for it to count as activity contributing to the badge.

Comment: There are some existing posts about this, way back in the day when the badge was first added. [For example.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21414/design-a-rube-goldberg-machine-to-achieve-the-fanatic-badge)

Comment: Someone did years ago, earning Fanatic on all the SE sites in existence at the time. I can't remember who and sorta can't be bothered to go and try to fish it out of the network-wide meta site.

Comment: Consecutive days where you haven't actually visited yourself is absolutely meaningless, and if the only way someone can feel good about themselves is to lie and cheat to earn things they haven't actually earned, I'm sad for them. It's the equivalence of getting a medal for bravery because you didn't get caught trampling an elderly person on the way out of a burning building but managed not to drop the puppy you were holding. If that makes a person feel good about themselves, what kind of person are they really?

Comment: @KenWhite When you ask a climber why they felt the need to climb up to the top of a mountain, you might get the answer "because it was there". We're programmers, (good) programmers are inquisitive by nature. Gaming that badge might just be about finding out if you can beat the system and not so much about the actual badge. I wouldn't assume that if someone did that, they did it just for the badge. I've hacked websites before just to see if I could do it, so I could totally see why someone would attempt such a script.

Comment: @ivarni: And when you ask that climber if "climbing to the top of the mountain" feels as good when they know they actually didn't climb, but took a helicopter up the back side of the mountain just so they could lie to everyone about climbing it, they'll tell you "No, I would never do that, because then it's not an accomplishment. It's a fraud, a lie, and it would make me feel really really bad about myself." There is no accomplishment if you're not doing the work to earn it, and while you may get away with lying to others, you'll know inside you're a fraud. (It also damages your credibility.)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm sorry, but you completely missed my point.

Comment: @ivami: No, I'm afraid you missed mine. The only challenge to be overcome with this question is to earn a badge that the poster isn't entitled to, which is simply gaming the system to fraudulently look better here than that person actually is; see his comment to the question ("Those badges really matter to some people!'). The entire point of badges here is to represent the actual effort you've put into the site, and if you feel the need to lie about that effort it's a slap in the face to the people who honestly earn them by working to get them.

Comment: @KenWhite For some people (hackers, and I mean that in the original meaning of that word) beating the system **is** the reward. Not the badge. You're projecting what you think is important onto others. Just because **you** think the badge is the goal doesn't mean **I** think that. Beating that particular system might just be another challenge to other people, and lots of people (hackers) love challenges. Don't blindly assume that everyone who would consider scripting it would do it for some silly badge.

Comment: Q: *"Why did you break that website's security"* A: *"Because it was there"*. That's what I meant with my analogy. I didn't miss your point, I rejected it.

Comment: @ivarni: *The poster himself* admitted the badge was the goal, in the comment I quoted. This is not "hacking" for the challenge. It's trying to game the system to earn rewards or privileges that haven't been earned. I rejected yours, because you're trying to represent this as some sort of honorable "hacker" goal while it's not.

Comment: Did you miss that comment from the OP just two spots under the one you cling to? Anyway, this is pointless. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 5):

> Can you automate visiting the site consecutive for X days?

Yes.
Although whether it's ethical or within site rules to do so is something *you'll* have to make sure of.

> Does it count towards the consecutive visited days

The exact requirements are not publicly known, so only Stack could answer this (and they won't) or your testing it, and I believe automating such tasks are against the rules.
So if you do, remember you've just provided public evidence it was you, AND how you are going to do it...

"Hey, Mr Policeman, if I went into that bank tomorrow at 2pm with a shotgun..."
"Yeeesss....?"

> If you were bored or fancied learning something new about HTTP requests, stackoverflow login/cookies, a new networking framework, networking in a new programming language, cron or just really wanted stackoverflow badges?

Surely the time spent doing all that is gazillions of time more than just logging in and using the site a bit?

Comment: Just to be clear:
1.) I said "Those badges really matter to some people". I did not say that I was included.

2.) I am not advocating doing this just by raising the question.

3.) It could bring to light faults of the badge or Stackoverflow verification methods as the point @ivarni raises.